# SAS find path with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, sas

I have a path in a variable, and now i want to match the path (with perl).

My problem is, i dont know how many folders the path has, and so how i can match the expression.

Example,some text with a path in it:

```
blablatext....
%include '/data/..../programm.sas';
/*.... is symbolic for an unknown number of folders
 first slash is optional*/
blablatext...
```

What i have done so far is this:

```
pattern = PRXPARSE("s/%include +\'(\/*\w+\/)\'/$1 /");
```

but this only matches  %include '/data/' or  %include 'data/'.
So how can i build an expression which matches an unknown number of folders and slashes in a string?

(Please excuse if this question is trivial, but i have not worked with regex since a long time and could not find a good solution today)

EDIT:
Also i would like to have a solution which returns only the Programname, without path, in this case just programm.sas or only programm.

Comment: Try `"s/.*%include +\'((?:\/[^\/]+)+)'.*/$1/"` or perhaps ``"s/.*%include +\'((?:\/[^\/]+)+)'.*/$1/s"``.

Comment: Hm, both did not work. Does it not need the \w+ for characters between slashes? What is the ?: for?

Comment: Maybe the non-capturing groups are not supported? Try removing `?:` and escaping `%` as `\%`.

Comment: You can extract only the program name using the scan function, its a bit more readable. `txt_file_name = scan(filename, -2, ".\")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pattern = PRXPARSE("/%include '.+\/([^']+)';/gi");
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tC1gF9/1)

Comment: Thx so far.i can Test this on monday. I hope the Syntax in sas is the same

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have the full path name you can use this macro (or convert it to an `fcmp` function):

```
%macro path(iFileName=);
  %sysfunc(prxchange(s/(.*[\\|\/])[^\\|\/]+$/$1/,1,&iFileName))
%mend;
```

Examples:

```
%put %path(iFileName=%sysfunc(getoption(config)));
```

> C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.3\

```
%put %path(iFileName=\\pc12345\sasdev\);
```

> \\pc12345\sasdev\

```
%put %path(iFileName=\\pc12345\sasdev);
```

> \\pc12345\

```
%put %path(iFileName=c:\something.txt);
```

> c:\

```
%put %path(iFileName=/usr/etc/x.txt);
```

> /usr/etc/

```
%put %path(iFileName=/usr/etc/);
```

> /usr/etc/

Below is the full code including an explanation of the regex:

```
/******************************************************************************
** PROGRAM:  MACRO.PATH.SAS
**
** DESCRIPTION: RETURNS THE FULL PATH FOR THE SUPPLIED FILENAME.  NOTE THIS 
**              PROGRAM DOES NOT VALIDATE THAT THE PATH EXISTS. 
**
** PARAMETERS: iFILENAME: THE FILENAME TO GET THE PATH FOR. IF IFILENAME
**                        IS A PATH (IE. FOLDER) AND NOT A FILE AND ENDS WITH
**                        EITHER A / OR A \ THEN THE PROGRAM WILL RETURN IT 
**                        UNCHANGED.  IF IT DOES NOT END WITH AN / OR \ THEN IT
**                        WILL RETURN THE PARENT FOLDER.
** 
** EXPLANATION OF PERL REGULAR EXPRESSION:
**
** prxchange(s/(.*[\\|\/])[^\\|\/]+$/$1/,   <== REGEX
**           1,                             <== POSITION TO START AT?
**           &iFileName)                    <== STRING TO APPLY REGEX TO
**
** s/                        <== INDICATES A SEARCH AND REPLACE EXPRESSION
** (.*[\\|\/])[^\\|\/]+$     <== THIS IS WHAT WE ARE SEARCHING FOR
** /$1                       <== THIS IS WHAT WE WILL REPLACE IT WITH
** /                         <== END OF REGEX
**
**
** (.*[\\|\/])   <== 1ST CAPTURE GROUP IS EVERYTHING BETWEEN ( AND )
**                   FINDING THE BIGGEST STRING WE CAN THAT ENDS WITH A FORWARDSLASH OR BACKSLASH
** [^\\|\/]+     <== FOLLOWED BY ONE OR MORE CHARACTERS THAT ARENT A FORWARDSLASH OR BACKSLASH. IE. / OR \
** $             <== FOLLOWED BY THE END OF THE STRING
**
** NOTE THAT IF A MATCHING STRING ISNT FOUND THEN THE STRING PASSED IN WILL REMAIN UNCHANGED
**
*******************************************************************************
** VERSION:
** 1.0 ON: 01DEC11 BY: RP
**     CREATED.  
******************************************************************************/

%macro path(iFileName=);
  %sysfunc(prxchange(s/(.*[\\|\/])[^\\|\/]+$/$1/,1,&iFileName))
%mend;
```

Comment: I should add that my regex-fu isn't the best so there's very likely better solutions out there.